# Optimization of laravel pivot table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a pivot table called `invite_riskarea` which is designed as follows:

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

This table stores the permissions that have a specific user (through an invite id) to give access to specific riskfields. Each riskfield is associated with a riskarea which acts as the main container of specific riskfields.

Within the model `Invite` I have this relationship:

```
public function riskareas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Riskarea::class)->withPivot('riskfield_id', 'insert', 'edit', 'view');
}
```

In this way I can return all the riskareas associated with a specific invite, and I should be able to return all the riskfields associated with a specific riskarea in the same invite model.

As you can see from the table `invite_riskarea` I have three columns called `insert, edit, delete`. These columns manage the types of permissions assigned to a specific user (via invite id) for a specific riskfield belonging to a riskarea.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve the riskarea permission in the following way:

```
$invite = Invite::where('id', 58)->first();
$riskarea = $invite->riskareas[0];
$riskfield = $riskareas->riskfields[0];
echo 'view permission => ' . $riskfield->insert;
```

The problem is that I'm not able to setup a correct relationship in the `Invite` model that returns the pivot data of the permissions columns only for the `riskfield` associated to the `riskarea`.

So I have managed to handle this situation in this way:

```
$riskareas = Riskarea::all();

foreach ($riskareas as &$riskarea) {
    foreach ($riskarea->riskfields as &$riskfield) {
        $result = DB::table('invite_riskarea')
            ->select('insert', 'edit', 'view')
            ->where([
                'riskarea_id' => $riskarea->id,
                'riskfield_id' => $riskfield->id
            ])
            ->first();

        if ($result) {
            $riskfield->insert = $result->insert;
            $riskfield->edit = $result->edit;
            $riskfield->view = $result->view;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I get all the riskareas, and then I iterate over the riskfields associated. For each riskfield, I get the permissions in the `invite_riskarea` table and then I have the correct structure that I want.

So to summarize:

1. Is it actually possible to create a model relationship that returns the permissions for riskfield and not for riskarea?
2. Is my table implementation good enough to handle that situation?

Comment: Have you thought about creating an `InviteRiskarea` model? This model can be used as a starting point to filter out all other data. You could also use Eager loading to improve performance. I suspect that your current loop is expensive to run.

Comment: @user3402600 I'm thinking another way and I would like to have your opinion about that. What about if I retrieve all the riskareas and then when I iterate over the riskfields associated to the riskarea, I check if the riskfield has a permission querying the table invite_riskfield? Do you think it's a good approach? It would be similar to the hasRole method of laratrust package. I just need to figure out how to implement this, may you could give me an help?

Answer (score 1):

## Your questions

It appears [the answer by Luidmila to your question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71431394/1575353) was helpful. The callback to the `whereHas` could be simplified using [an arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) as long as the server is running PHP 7.4 or newer (which is hopefully the case [given LTS](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)). Doing this would allow the elimination of the `use` statement for `$invite_id`.

## Review

There isn't much code here to review but below are some critiques.

### Simpler method to find a model instance

While it may just be sample code, the code contains this line:

> ```
> $invite = Invite::where('id', 58)->first();
> ```

The code for the invite model was not included but the entity relationship diagram depicts that the `id` field is the primary key. One could use the [`find()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections#method-find) instead of `where` to simplify finding the invitation by the `id` field. There are also [helper methods like `findOrFail` which may be helpful in certain scenarios](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions).

### repeated lines to set values from result

In the example code there are also these three lines

> ```
> $riskfield->insert = $result->insert;
> $riskfield->edit = $result->edit;
> $riskfield->view = $result->view;
> ```

Bearing in mind that these lines may not be needed anymore, there may be other places where the pattern occurs.

In such a case, a loop could be used to simplify these lines - especially if four or more properties need to be assigned:

```
foreach (['insert', 'edit', 'view'] as $property) {
    $riskfield->$property = $result->$property;
}
```